# How to add custom line and improve this code?

Tags: tables, formatting, line

I have work from my campus, but, not all is learned, so I must develop this script, so, I have problem about text and table. I need to compile like this.

I have use `\hline` but that will line everything up.

[image: EXAMPLE]

```
\documentclass[a4, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Nama    : Justin & No & KD-MK & Mata Kuliah & SKS & Kelas
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is `a4paper`, not `a4`. Btw you don't have `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I was taught to use a4 not a4paper, maybe from the teacher it was wrong, thanks for ur correction.

I deleted some code, because I think if I post everything will be long

Answer (score 1):

You can use command `cline{2-6}` like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}

\begin{document} % <====================================================
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \cline{2-6} % <=======================================================
  Nama    : Justin & No & KD-MK       & Mata Kuliah & SKS & Kelas \\
  \cline{2-6} % <=======================================================
  Class   : 1CCAB  & 1  & Geographics & IT11234     &     &       \\
  \cline{2-6} % <=======================================================
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting table]

But better would be the following table I think (see the starting column divided in three with `lcl`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}

\begin{document} % <====================================================
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{lcl|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \cline{4-8} % <=======================================================
  Nama &:& Justin & No & KD-MK       & Mata Kuliah & SKS & Kelas \\
  \cline{4-8} % <=======================================================
  Class&:& 1CCAB  & 1  & Geographics & IT11234     &     &       \\
  \cline{4-8} % <=======================================================
       & &        & 2  & Geographics & IT11235     &     &       \\
  \cline{4-8} % <=======================================================
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result two]

Comment: why at syntax \cline use 4-8